# where can we find fcm firebase pusnotification api key firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

To publish my app on google play store, I need to change $api_access_key in the following code with mine, How can I do that?
class Pushnotification {

```
public $CI;
//com.qdocs.smartschool
public $API_ACCESS_KEY = "AAAAkGeJt3E:APA91bEITzLONxgN9bFDgpvZTgXdqCe23JVcC_96cfHiLJzMiN-oOO1lc15OULp1pUxH0uHljFnTX72b2ELQazuFNTjt3dK-flPO_iDUXnSEFjFlHJQW2r2mF4SuzkaL0wJPE-6UealO";

public $fcmUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Enter Your Project, and go to `setting` and then `project settings`

[image]

You Will Find the `Messaging` Tab, go down and you will find `server key`, if you did not find it then generate a `new one`

[image]